# Easy way to convert 4 space indentation to 2

Tags: xcode, terminal, indentation

I use 4-space indentation for all of my own work. I've picked up a large project from a client where they insist on 2-space indentation. I've already touched hundreds of lines of codes across many source files before finding this out.

Xcode is the IDE I'm using here but I'm open to any solution. I'd like to find some way that can just walk through the project and auto format the indentation.

I've been looking for a bit but I mainly find people hand waving about tabs vs spaces, 4 vs 2, etc. I've also run across indent, expand, and unexpand commands but they don't seem to be quite right.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are quite a few different tools for this kind of thing, e.g. [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net)

Comment: If your code is written in Perl you can easily format with perltidy: `perltidy -i=2 -b <filename.pl>`. Also I recommend to use option `-pbp`

Answer (score 15):

There is a solution that is almost doing what was asked within Xcode itself. Maybe not in 2013, but now there is an additional option Editor->Structure->Re-indent (ctrl-i) that changes the indentation of all selected lines to your editor setting. So if it is just about a few files, issuing cmd-a ctrl-i should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace all (4 spaces) with (2 spaces), right?

Comment: That's too general. Too much danger of causing side effects in code somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but how would any program that did this for you be any less dangerous? I suppose you could only apply the replace to the beginning of lines before any non-white-space characters.

Comment: Yep. That's what I'd probably have to build.

Answer (score 0):

What language(s) are you working with?

There is probably a language specific script that will do the job for you.  Some examples:

tidy - HTML Tidy - Utility to clean up and pretty print HTML/XHTML/XML

perltidy - a perl script indenter and reformatter

pythontidy - ditto for python